# Вопрос об upcast в c#

Tags: c#, .net

Есть код:

```
class Parent
{
    public virtual void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent");
    }
}

class Tort : Parent
{
    public override void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("tort");
    }
}

class Karamelka : Parent
{
    public override void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("karamelka");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Parent tort = new Tort();
        tort.Say();
        ((Karamelka)tort).Say();
    }
}
```

Как мне превратить объект Tort в Karamelka или в Parent, чтобы он использовал другую реализацию метода Say()? Сейчас вызывается исключение InvalidCastException

Comment: а зачем это может понадобиться? есть какая-то более практическая задача, зачем это нужно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Привести тип `Tort` к типу `Karamelka` не получится, так как класс `Tort` не является наследником класса `Karamelka`.

Приведение `Tort` к `Parent` в вашем коде уже присутствует:

```
Parent tort = new Tort();
```

Но использовать реализацию метода `Say()`, отличную от той, что в классе Tort не получится. 
Но можно внести следующие изменения:
в классе `Tort` исправьте `public override void Say()` на `public new void Say()`.

Работать это будет так:

```
Tort tort = new Tort();
tort.Say(); // "tort"
((Parent)tort).Say(); // "Parent"
```

Comment: Простите, но может есть какие-то способы заменить одну реализацию метода в классе другой при помощи рефлексии?

Comment: Нет, при помощи рефлексии не получится.

Comment: @mirypoko, можете описать свою задачу более подробно, подскажем решение. Но менять реализацию метода в классе при помощи рефлексии - неправильно и не представляется возможным.

Comment: @mirypoko если нужно временно заменить реализацию метода - используйте декоратор - дешево и сердито

Answer (score 3):

Если хотите правильно реализовать с практический точки зрение, тогда нужна реализовать паттерн стратегия в этом ситуации.
В этом ситуации наследование не улучшает а наоборот уменьшает сопровождаемость.
примерно должны писать вот так:

```
  class Dessert
    {
        public virtual void Say(Action<string> predicate,string info)
        {
            predicate(info);
        }
    }



    class Program
    {

        static void DefaultSay(string info)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(info);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dessert tort = new Dessert();
            tort.Say(DefaultSay, "tort");

            Dessert karamel = new Dessert();
            karamel.Say(DefaultSay, "karamel");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```